# Creating a SET then populating the set with 200 numbers between 10000 + 1, then proceeding to print out each number that is even inside of the set

Tags: c++, lambda, foreach, set, countif

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

//Create a set object to store a set of 200 randomly generated numbers from 1 to 10000. Use the for_each function and an anonymous function to display all the even numbers in the set.

using namespace std;

template <typename t>
void prints(t even) {
    void prints(t even) {
        if (even % 2) == 0;
        cout << "All the even numbers in the set are: " << even;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    set<int> nums;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        nums.insert(rand() % 10000 + 1);
    }
    int gt50 = count_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int n) {return (n % 2) == 0}); // this is the issue it says I need ;, but when I put it nothing works. 

    for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), prints<int>);
}
```

I do not understand why, at the end of line 32 it is asking me to Implement the ; command to end of a line when I do so it still proceeds to give me the same issue. Regardless I don't understand why thats doing what its doing as I've used my debugger but cannot find anything out.

Comment: Dare I ask what is with the non-standard nested function with invalid syntax? Also, your for-loop has no guarantee of populating 200 unique elements. That for-loop should be `while (nums.size() != 200)`

Comment: Also, your lambda is missing a semi-colon. `[](int n) {return (n % 2) == 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you run your compiler, it will show you several errors:

[image]

So, the compiler tells you the problem and where it is.

Then, after removing they problematic issues and correcting semantic bug in the for loops condition, you will get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

//Create a set object to store a set of 200 randomly generated numbers from 1 to 10000. Use the for_each function and an anonymous function to display all the even numbers in the set.

using namespace std;

template <typename t>
void prints(t even) {
    if ((even % 2) == 0) 
        cout << even << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    set<int> nums;
    for (int i = 0; nums.size() < 200; i++) {
        nums.insert(rand() % 10000 + 1);
    }
    int gt50 = count_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int n) {return (n % 2) == 0; }); // this is the issue it says I need ;, but when I put it nothing works. 

    for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), prints<int>);
}
```

This will work.